# Can we use DbContext pool (EF Core) in multi tenancy Individual database per tenant

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant

We are working on multi tenancy application where for each tenant we have Separate/individual database.
We are using EF core dbcontext ,my question is :

1-Does dbcontext pooling works for this scenario

2-We are creating context in each request based on tenatid present in request ,so how we will achieve contextPooling ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14625#issuecomment-1199446972

Comment: it is not pooled everytime it returns new instance of dbcontext even if tenant is smae

Comment: What do you mean??

     var dbContext = _pooledDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using SetConnectionString() method.
I have created Middleware in which based on request client I am getting connection string and setting to Dbcontext using

```
_dbcontext.DataBase.CloseConnection()
_dbcontext.DataBase.SetConnectionString(conn);
```